# Installing AudioKit Core with Carthage

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, carthage

When intalling AudioKit with Cocoapods there's a subspec called Core you can use:

Podspec URL: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/1/6/8/AudioKit/4.10.1/AudioKit.podspec.json

Is there an equivalent way of only installing the Core library with Carthage?